# Add contents to an mongodb object array from nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongodb object, the model is given below, I want to add contents to the existing array

```
var UsersSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String, 
    required: true
       },   
EmpId: {
    type:  string,
    required: true
           },
feed:[{
       status: {
        type: String
               },
       comments: {
        type: String
               },
        posted_date: {
        type: Date,
        default : Date.now
               }
    }]
  });
```

using a PUT or POST can I add contents to an existing document's feed array.please check the below code

```
router.put('/api/user1', function(request, response){

Model.findById(request.body._id, function(err, user){
    console.log(user.feed);
    if(err){
        response.status(404).send(err);
    }
    else {
        user.update(
                {_id: user._id }, 
                { $addToSet:
        { feed: user.feed  }})
    }
        })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use $push to add to an array in Mongo after you find your document.

```
user.update(
    {_id: user._id }, 
    { $push:
    { feed: user.feed  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`user.update({_id: user.id}, {$addToSet: {feed: {$each: user.feed}}});`

If you use `$addToSet` or `$push` without `$each` it will push the entire array onto the array in mongo, not each entry.